# Django Rest Framework: How to map JSON field to serializer

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I've a JSON which have a key "myKey", I want my serializer in such a way that "myKey" maps to "youKey" field in serializer class. How can I make this type of serializers?

Comment: do you have a more specific example of what you are trying to solve?